# AngularJS - Best Place for Custom Elements Configuration

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Greetings Overflowers,

What is the best practice regarding passing configuration information that will affect specific custom elements behaviour or style?

What I have in mind: as behaviorless custome attributes (i.e. that have no directives defined for them).

Example:
I want to configure my custom  element because I have "Press" and "Toggle" buttons.
Shall I use a custom attribute such as al:type="Toggle", for example, which is not defined as directive (have no affect on my element's behavior, i.e. dummy attribute)? Or there is a better best-practice way?

Kind regards

Comment: If the configuration is gloabal in nature, I'd suggest you consider using a service. http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services. If it isn't global, I'm not clear on what you mean by behavior less customm attributes. Please add an example.

Comment: question is far too vague and ambiguous. First sentence conflicts with second sentence with regard to purpose of attributes.

Comment: As mentioned, please provide examples. What have you tried already, what were the issues?

Answer (score 1):

(If I'm understanding your question correctly..) there isn't a standardized way of doing this, but angular-ui handles this by allowing you to specify the name of a 'value' object that's been registered with the dependency injector.  Hard to explain, [much easier to show](http://angular-ui.github.com/#/directives-jq) (check out the jquery passthrough under 'how' for an example).

The convention that I personally follow is something like this:

```
<div myDirective="optionsFn()">foo</div>
```

where 'optionsFn' returns the options from my controller.